# Fire event only when focus is moved outside of any of an element's children

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I want to fire an event when **and only when** the user focuses somewhere other than a child element of the `div`, e.g. when focus is transferred from `input1` to `input3`:

```
<div onfocusout="console.log(document.activeElement)">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
</div>

<input type="text" id="input3">
```

However, the focusout event is being triggered even when focus shifts within elements of the `div`, e.g. when focus is transferred from `input1` to `input2`. To make matters worse, `document.activeElement` always resolves `body` at the instant focusout is triggered (suggesting that focus rolls all the way back to the `body` before moving back to `input2`) so I can't even manually verify where the new focus ends up before the focusout is triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the `relatedTarget` property of the `event` passed to the handler to see which element is getting the new focus:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
container.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  console.log(e.relatedTarget);
  if (!container.contains(e.relatedTarget)) console.log('focus is now outside of container');
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
</div>

<input type="text" id="input3">
```